# PDO как составить правильно запрос к базе данных?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Приветствую господа профессионалы, не могу разобраться с pdo, вот есть код:

```
//Эту страку хочу разбить и засунуть в массив
$variable = "userName#userSurname#userTelefon#userEmail#userPasword_1#userPasword_2";

$pieces = explode("#", $variable);

//Вызиваю функцию и подставляю значения с массива 
in_db("INSERT INTO authorized_user SET name = $pieces[0], surname = $pieces[1], mail = $pieces[2], telefon = $pieces[3], pass = $pieces[4]");

//Сама функция для работы с базой данных 
function in_db($db_dt){ 

    $db_server = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'rem_teh_servis';
    $db_user = 'rem_teh_site';
    $db_password = 'thrtu4hr5u4u';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8";

    // Параметры задают что в качестве ответа получаем ассоциативный массив
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE  => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );

    try { 
    
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password, $opt); 

        // Формируем запрос
        $result = $pdo->query($db_dt);

    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) { die('Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->$db_dt); }
}
```

Как привести данный код в рабочее состояние? Я уже отчаялся и не знаю даже как задать правильно вопрос

Comment: ну так что происходит то? ошибку видите какую-то или не видите, или данные не добавляются или что вообще? Если думаете что с этим кодом что-то не так, то хоть напишите что именно не так

Comment: для начала вам надо изучить синтаксис оператора insert в SQL. Затем освоить подстановку параметров  в SQL запрос (оно будет работать и в том виде как у вас написана подставновка прямо в строку, но в общем случаев это чревато, проблемами). Если освоите биндинг параметров, то можно не париться с отсутствующими кавычками в запросое.

Comment: Спасибо, биндинг для меня слово новое, буду изучать, и да при выполнении кода выбивает ошибку "Подключение не удалось" и данные не заносятся в БД

Comment: так надо использовать сведения об ошибке, а не просто выводить "какая-то ошибка". mysql в исключении возвращает текст ошибки, будет у вас там укзаано, что непонятный синтаксис рядом с `set field1 = string value , field2 =  что-то еще без кавычек`. Вы строки в запрос передаете, но не заключаете их в кавычки.

Comment: в целом у вас должно получиться что-то вроде `$st = $pdo->prepare("... set name = ?, surname = ?"); $st->execute($pieces);`

Comment: А зачем вообще вот это ` catch (PDOException $e) { die('Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->$db_dt); }`?